# We are getting some exception, Exception message: "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<FactInspection>()

Tags: .net-core

While update the .netcore 2.2 to 3.1, I am facing the issue.

> ```
> .Where(f => f.Media_Id == __filter_MediaId_0 && f.Targeted_Date != null && f.Targeted_Date.Value.Date >= __filter_StartDate_Value_Date_1 && f.Targeted_Date.Value.Date <= __filter_EndDate_Value_Date_2)
>    .GroupBy(
>        keySelector: f => new { 
>            Targeted_Year = f.Targeted_Year, 
>            Targeted_Quarter = f.Targeted_Quarter, 
>            Targeted_Quater_Range = f.Targeted_Quater_Range, 
>            Phase = f.Phase == \"Completed\" ? \"Completed\" : \"Not >Completed\"
>         }, 
>        elementSelector: f => f)
>    .Select(e => new TargetDashboardResponse{ 
>        Targeted_Year = (Nullable<int>)e.Key.Targeted_Year.Value, 
>        Quarter = e.Key.Targeted_Quarter, 
>        Name = string.Format(
>            format: \"{0} ({1})\", 
>            arg0: e.Key.Targeted_Quater_Range, 
>            arg1: (object)e.Key.Targeted_Year), 
>        Phase = e.Key.Phase, 
>        Count = e
>            .Count() 
>    }
>    )
>    .OrderBy(e0 => e0.Targeted_Year)'
> ```
>
> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.", Inner exception: "" , Stacktrace: "   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.g__CheckTranslated|15_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass15_0& )

Comment: Did the answer below help you?

Answer (score -2):

Exception message clearly says to add a call to one of these methods:
 *' AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'* at the end of your query.

```
For example: await (your query).ToListAsync()
```